# Error compiling - makefile - include header

Tags: c, makefile, header, include

I have a problem that I can't seem to resolve. I'm trying with the `-I` flag to add my includes to the list of which the compiler will look at. Instead of directly looking in the /usr/include directory which contains all the standard library, it will look first in my include directory for header files. But it doesn't seem to find the files since a long list of this kind of error appears when I compile:

```
src/termcaps/termcapbis.c:13:10: fatal error: 'termcaps.h' file not found #include <termcaps.h>
```

(That is one example out of multiple errors that all say the same thing.)

So I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my Makefile or if I have to do something else for the compiler to understand where my header files are.

Here's my makefile:

```
NAME = 42sh

SRC_DIR = "src"
SRC_DIRS = $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type d -follow -print)
SRC_FILES = $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type f -follow -print | grep      "\.c")

OBJ_DIR = "obj"
OBJ_DIRS = $(SRC_DIRS:$(SRC_DIR)%=$(OBJ_DIR)%)
OBJ_FILES = $(SRC_FILES:$(SRC_DIR)%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)%.o)

FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
INCLUDE = -Iinclude -Ilibft/include
LIB = -Llibft -lft -ltermcap

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ_FILES)
    make -C libft
    gcc $(FLAGS) $^ $(LIB) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIRS) $(OBJ_DIR)
    gcc $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    @make fclean -C libft

fclean: clean
    @rm -rf $(NAME)
    @make fclean -C libft

re: fclean $(NAME)

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't YELL at us!

Comment: It's the source file which is faulty, not the makefile.

Comment: Does the code compile without using the makefile?  If so, what command line do you use to compile it successfully?  Is the header really `<termcaps.h>` (plural) rather than `<termcap.h>` (singular)?

Comment: Sorry for the title ^^ What do you mean by the source file? They are several source files, like 40 of them. And in each and everyone of them I include my headers like that: "#include <name_of_header.h>". I check for typo-like error and this isn't it. I've never tried to compile without the Makefile, the command line would be way too long to type...

Comment: Can you list the header `termcaps.h`?  Which directory is it found in?  Which directory is the makefile in?

Comment: So basically my repository is like that: 
first directory: -src -obj -include -Makefile.
sub-directory of src: -termcap/termcaps.c.
And in this specific file and all the others my include looks like this : `#include <termcaps.h>`

Comment: First, you should include your personal headers using the `#include "header.h"` style. `#include <header.h>` is more suited for system header.
Secondly, could you provide the actual command-line that the Makefile pass to the shell ? That would help to find out what the problem is.